# Can the magnetosphere penetrate the walls of the ISS (International Space Station)?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, space, ferromagnetism, geomagnetism

I'll assume that compared to the size of the ISS, the geomagnetic field is uniform over a small region.  In that case, could that magnetic field be measured inside the ISS?  To illustrate the question:

[image: uniform magnetic field around cylinder]

If we consider a cross-section of a module on the ISS (a cylinder), what does the magnetic field look like inside?

It seems the wall is made of *a layer of ceramic-fiber or kevlar mesh material between the exterior thin aluminum sheet (2mm) and the aluminum pressure hull (3mm).* [[ref1](https://www.quora.com/Does-the-ISS-have-any-micrometeorite-shielding), [ref2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/could-a-gun-fired-inside-the-iss-rupture-it)], so the surface is a conductor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a clear yes (which you can see directly in measurements of the magnetic field taken inside the ISS).

https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/astro-pi-flight-data-analysis/worksheet/

Since Aluminium is not ferromagnetic this makes sense.  It would still be interesting to understand the "shape" of the magnetic field inside the region outlined above.

Comment: It'll look extremely noisy. All that electric equipment generates its own magnetic field, but now with much stronger spatial variations.

Comment: The fields from all the stuff on the ISS can be huge compared to Earth's rather small field (~30,000 nT).  Even spacecraft buses produce significant enough fields that they need to be removed when making magnetic field measurements in space plasmas.

Comment: @honeste_vivere, Why would it be different from the interference from electronics / electrical appliances in a normal home vs. the small magnetic field of the Earth?  The data I linked above (measured inside the ISS) shows a pretty clean curve without "huge" disruptions.

Comment: Oh, I am sure they can measure it I am just saying that the induced fields from geomagnetic storms etc. are quite small compared to the fields generated by the station and instruments on board.